# Hidden text feature using < !-- --> . Where is this documented?

Tags: discussion, markdown, spoilers

When you go over the text below with mouse it appears.
I saw this in a question somewhere and am wondering where on meta-so or so it is documented.

> This is very cool but where is it documented?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The spoiler quote in your question has nothing to do with `<!-- -->`, which is a HTML comment. Text included between the `<!--` and the `-->` will simply not appear, and is of limited use on Stack Exchange (but it *does have* some usefulness occasionally).

It has everything to do with using `>!` at the beginning of your line, which is a spoiler quote:

> Kapow

It's documented in our [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#spoilers) but goes unmentioned in our [formatting help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). (Thanks, [nnnnnn](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/163918/nnnnnn)!)

Comment: It is mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#spoilers).

Comment: @nnnnnn Thanks! I've added that. :)